# Atomic integer count in MongoDB using the C# Drivers

Tags: c#, mongodb, atomic

I have an object in Mongo that looks like this:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("59bffce310b7213b6c812f53"), 
  "Key" : 1.0, 
  "LatestCardId" : 1.0
}
```

I'm trying to preserve an id I use across the system. I want it to be unique so I have a collection just for this id. I will only have one instance keeping track of the id. I want to then use it to create an entry in another collection. That object will then be returned to the user so they can use my new id to access the main collection.

My issue is with the Update.Inc statement in the C# Driver (v2.4.4). I've stripped everything back, read the docs and am struggling to understand an exception I'm getting.

The database is connecting fine and here's my code:

```
var idCollection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Key", 1);
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Inc("LatestCardId", filter);
var result = await idCollection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

I then get this exception:

`{"A write operation resulted in an error.\r\n  Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: {LatestCardId: { _t: \"SimpleFilterDefinition`2\" }}"}`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong. It's late so I've probably been quite stupid. Any help appreciated.

As an aside, does anyone know how I'd do this using the strongly typed C# version of Mongo, e.g.

```
var idCollection = database.GetCollection<CardIdObj>(collectionName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be what you are looking for, including your strongly typed collection.

```
var idCollection = database.GetCollection<CardIdObj>("CardIdObj");

var filter = Builders<CardIdObj>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Key, 1);
var update = Builders<CardIdObj>.Update.Inc(x => x.LatestCardId, 1);
var result = idCollection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

It appears that you are trying to Increment your LatestCardId with your filter, which is not going to work.

Or if you wish to keep using your magic string:

```
var idCollection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("CardIdObj");

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Key", 1);
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Inc("LatestCardId", 1);
var result = idCollection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```